# Build Maven project with local dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ant

I downloaded old project, which based on Eclipse, Ant or something else, I don't know this build system (I use Maven\Gradle). Project sources  was converted to Maven manually, but project had more jar libraries. They were imported in project with help of IDEA (`Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies`), but libraries defined only in `.iml` file.

When I tried to build project in .jar with help of Maven — Maven show errors, that it cannot find classes from libraries (but in sources all good). I found in Internet example, like in this code sample:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>example</groupId>
        <artifactId>example</artifactId>
        <version>examle</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/example.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

But this don't help. Libraries are old too, and they created by old build tools, which don't write artifact id, group id and etc., so I don't know this information.

---

How I can write dependencies on local .jar libraries in `pom.xml` if I don't know information (group, artifact ids) about they?

---

**UPD_0:**

When I try to set only system path to library, I take this:

[image]

Comment: Upload such jar into a repository manager and use it as usual dependency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is set correct path in  the

```
 <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/example.jar</systemPath>
```

group, artifact ids and version are user defined information. So you can define it as you wish.

Comment: I try this, but it don't work. See updated question.

Comment: you should set groupid and artifactid. use any names what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install this jar in ur local repository from command line / terminal like this. Then add the dependency with the package and version given by you in the command without scope as system

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path>/example.jar
-DgroupId=com.something
-DartifactId=example
-Dversion=<give some version>
-Dpackaging=jar
-DgeneratePom=true
```